# Speeding up Vlookups

Tags: vlookup

When you do a Vlookup on a large database of say 80,000 rows, its gets slower and slwer as weach time it starts from the top and works through til it finds it. If its ordered then the first time its quick and each time its slightly slower.

Is there any way to avoid this, to make each subsequent lookup start from the place of the previous one.

Or remove a row each time it matches it, so database gets smaller.

Is there another method?

Comment: You can't ask for tools, it's off topic, so I edited your question. The answer is yes, you can do this with VBa but, it really depends on *what* it is your doing. I mean, if you use VLOOKUP the idea is to look up an entire column. But I think you only want to look "down" from the current row, is this correct?

Comment: If the lists are linked in such a way that you know you don't need to lookup everything each time, change the VLOOKUP formula to use an OFFSET instead of the full table.

Comment: "Other" methods would be to use the data model to act on the 2 tables as proper relational data. You then create a 3rd table from the model. You can do that pretty easily using Microsoft's free PowerQuery adding too if you are allowed addins.

Comment: excel isn't a database. Its a spreadsheet software. At some point, things *will* break down, performancewise.

Comment: Thanks those are super ideas I like OFFSET and Power query I will go away and research those. I know what you mean about the database its just one of those things where you write something then keep adding to it, it retrospect we should have a started with a database.

Comment: We use a name for the range, is there a way to make the range set in a name change or will I just need to rewrite the lookup to set the range and use offset to change this range each time it looks up?